# Quantum computer versus Random 3-SAT?

Tags: np-hardness, complexity-classes, quantum-computing, average-case-complexity

It seems to be commonly believed that a quantum computer cannot efficiently solve NP-hard problems. What about problems that are challenging in the average-case, such as Planted Clique and Random 3-SAT?

Comment: No, there is no known efficient quantum algorithm for these problems.